# функция для анализа одного столбца

Tags: c, функции

Возможно ли сильно не изменяя обе функции сделать из них функции для анализа не всех столбцов матрицы, а какой-нибудь определенной? Переписывать сильно не хочется, так как по сути "скелет" есть, но как из него сделать то, что нужно в голову не приходит

```
int minus_count(int** A, int rows, int colNo)
{
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        cnt += (A[i][colNo] < 0); /*Для отрицательного дает 1*/
    return cnt;
} /*Подсчет кол-ва <0 элементов в столбце*/
void check_2minus(int** A, int rows, int cols)
{
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; ++i)
        if (minus_count(A, rows, i) == 2) {
            printf("Столбец %d содержит два отрицательных элемента\n", i);
            k++;
        }
    if (k == 0) {
        printf("В матрице нет двух отрицательных элемента содержащихся в одном столбце.\n");
    }
```

Comment: Функция `minus_count` как раз анализирует не все столбцы, а только столбец с индексом `colNo`. Просто вызовите её для интересующего столбца: `int k = minus_count(A, rows, 3);`. Теперь в переменной `k` хранится количество отрицательных элементов в _четвёртом_ столбце матрицы `A`.

Comment: сможете ответить на вопрос, чтобы его закрыть?

Comment: Если хотите, можете самостоятельно написать ответ на основе комментария.